# How to initialize a generic class in an external package

Tags: generics, .net-core, initialization, scroll-paging

I am trying to initialize a generic class with an object type, however am unable to do it.

Below code will explain what I mean:

```
PagingList<MyForm> Form = new  PagingList<MyForm>();
```

So PagingList is my generic class and I have assigned the type "MyForm", however am unable to initialize it.

The error is :

"PagingList' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"

PagingList is a package which I added externally. MyForm is a class which I have created.

How could I initialize this?

Thank you.

Comment: you need to provide some values e.g. ```var form = new PagingList<T>(value1, value2);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an instance of the class you need to call a constructor of this class like you do:

```
new PagingList<MyForm>();
```

You try to call the default constructor that takes no arguments.

The error you see means that there is no constructor in PagingList class that takes 0 arguments. Check in the object browser if there are other constructors with 1 or more parameters or static methods that instantiates this class.

If you want you can refer to the documentation for more details on constructors: [C# Classes Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)